# npm cordova warn engine windows

Tags: windows, node.js, cordova, npm

I'm trying to install cordova via the command line. I'm get this error:

```
npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":
"0.12.0","npm":"2.5.1"})
npm WARN engine cordova-js@3.8.0: wanted: {"node":"~0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"
0.12.0","npm":"2.5.1"})
npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {
"node":"0.12.0","npm":"2.5.1"})
C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Roaming\npm\cordova -> C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Roaming\npm
\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova
cordova@4.3.0 C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova
├── underscore@1.7.0
├── q@1.0.1
├── nopt@3.0.1 (abbrev@1.0.5)
└── cordova-lib@4.3.0 (valid-identifier@0.0.1, osenv@0.1.0, properties-parser@0.
2.3, bplist-parser@0.0.6, mime@1.2.11, unorm@1.3.3, semver@2.0.11, dep-graph@1.1
.0, shelljs@0.3.0, rc@0.5.2, npmconf@0.1.16, xcode@0.6.7, through2@0.6.3, elemen
ttree@0.1.5, request@2.47.0, glob@4.0.6, d8@0.4.4, init-package-json@1.3.0, tar@
1.0.2, plist@1.1.0, cordova-js@3.8.0, npm@1.3.4)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't worry it's just warnings but not errors. The packages which you are installing require different minimal versions of node.js. But your version of node.js (0.12.0) is ok for them too

Comment: Kevin, if answer helped you, please, mark it as accepted. It will add green tick icon for this answer

Comment: I have same warnings - its : Cordova-js@4.0.0 : wanted node ~0.10.x Current : 0.12.6 npm 2.11.2  --  npm@1.3.4 : wanted node ~0.6.x Current : 0.12.6 npm 2.11.2  --  xmlbuilder@2.2.1 : wanted node ~0.6.x Current : 0.12.6 npm 2.11.2 -- Is it fine?