# how to install cordova,Ionic installation on yosemite(mac)

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, ionic-framework

```
npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":"0.12.2","npm":"2.7.4"})

npm WARN engine cordova-js@3.8.0: wanted: {"node":"~0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.2","npm":"2.7.4"})

npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.2","npm":"2.7.4"})

npm WARN installMany normalize-package-data was bundled with npm@1.3.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree

/Users/vimukthi/.node/bin/cordova -> 

/Users/vimukthi/.node/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova

cordova@4.3.0 /Users/vimukthi/.node/lib/node_modules/cordova


├── underscore@1.7.0

├── q@1.0.1

├── nopt@3.0.1 (abbrev@1.0.5)

└── cordova-lib@4.3.0 (valid-identifier@0.0.1, osenv@0.1.0, properties-

parser@0.2.3, bplist-parser@0.0.6, mime@1.2.11, semver@2.0.11, unorm@1.3.3,

 shelljs@0.3.0, dep-graph@1.1.0, elementtree@0.1.5, xcode@0.6.7, rc@0.5.2,

 d8@0.4.4, through2@0.6.3, npmconf@0.1.16, glob@4.0.6, plist@1.1.0, 

request@2.47.0, npm@1.3.4, init-package-json@1.4.0, tar@1.0.2, cordova-

js@3.8.0)

Vimukthis-iMac:~ vimukthi$ npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} 

(current: {"node":"0.12.2","npm":"2.7.4"

-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('e
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28973192/2752265) answer:

> Don't worry it's just warnings but not errors. The packages which you are installing require different minimal versions of node.js. But your version of node.js (0.12.0) is ok for them too